# numato mimas v2 interfacing with ddr ram

Tags: fpga

I am a newbie here, I used and have my hand on arduino, but now I got task of taking 3000 samples of waveform  with 100MSPS with an adc.

As this was impossible with arduino and most of the controller I switch to FPGA,
And bought NUMATO MIMAS v2 (As it has on board 512Mb DDR RAM, which is capable of handling that much fast operation.)

And also bought AD9283 along with it as it has 100MSPS 8bit adc output.
I am using Xilinx ISE, and using Verilog(No specific reason for it).

**My PROBLEM is** I am unable to interface that inbuilt DDR ram and communicate with it.
Means there are no tutorial to write on that ram and read from it.
So can any one could help me on it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read some file from Xilinx about Spartan 6.Like [ug416](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/mig/v3_8/ug416.pdf) and [ug388](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug388.pdf) .

Then you can make a Example Design (tutorial) for your board to simulation and communicate with DDR on real board.It is describe in ug416 page 67.You do not code as you creat a MIG IP.It creat a test file automatic.After you simulaion and verify on your board you will familiar with MIG IP.You shoud make sure these questions in this step.Like How many write/read path you will use?How to manage command path?How to addressing?What's the frequency do you need?And so on.

At last you can use MIG by your demand.If you just has only one stream data you will use MIG very easy.Like just use one write path and one read path.

Forgive my English.

Comment: The problem here is to use MIG or any soft core I need to buy full version of xilinx to access EDK. Is there any other way around?

Comment: You do not need to access EDK.Because you do not use CPU core in FPGA.I just know use MIG to communicate to DDR.Maybe there some open core you can use.@Yatin

Comment: yes I was successful at interfacing.
But as you said we don't write code in it! That's where the problem start. I came from controller programming background and I am not understanding how to tell him to read the data at specific time and write at specific time without coding it?
How will fpga know that I am using MIG when i will code using ISE (how to include MIG part with main code (something like we include library in c)) .

Comment: For first question: You can do some control work like you add a cache like circuit.It can make write operate have more space to cache.It can make some pre_read operate that can make your read have less wait time. For second question you just add files that produced by MIG.But you have to make a wrapper for it.I suggest you to read the MIG produced example project first.@Yatin